# LiveData is not re-emitting when fragment is resumed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

In my fragment, I have this code:

```
fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val state = liveData {
        val state = dataSource.getState()
        emit(state)
   }

}
```

When I navigate to another fragment or activity, and press back button, Fragment's `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` methods are called, but `viewModel.state` has the same value. I mean, `dataSource.getState()` is not called again. I need state to be re-fetched from data source.

Is this possible using `liveData` builder? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: try to put viewModel.state.observe...at onResume, and remove observer at onPause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just cal load function every time when it needed. One of possible way to do it

ViewModel :

```
val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<>()
    fun loadData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val state = dataSource.getState()
            stateLiveData.setValue(state)
        }
    }
```

Fragment :

```
fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    viewModel.loadData()
    viewModel.stateLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid calling a function. But if there is no choice...